# Efficient ways to retrieve a sorted list from bucket sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, priority-queue, bucket-sort

When the distribution of keys is sparse in bucket sort, there may be a lot of empty buckets.
How could we retrieve the sorted list (i.e., achieve the concatenation operation) efficiently?

We want to implement an bucket based priority queue, but the search for the first non-empty bucket may take lots of time. So we wonder a smarter way to do so.

For example, if we got a list with millions of 10, 1000, 50000, 100000, 6400000, 10000000 and so on, how could we retrieve the sorted list by using bucket sort?

Another tougher example would be, 1, 100, 101, ..., 999, 1000, 100000, 100001, ... 999999, 1000000, 100000000, 100000001, ..., 199999999.

There could be even harder cases that the distributions within some segments are dense, but there might be huge gaps between segments.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking here. Are you asking how to skip over empty buckets during the combining pass of bucket sort, or are you asking how to make an efficient bucket-based priority queue? You'll have to give a bit more detail before we can understand what you want, much less provide a reasonable answer.

Comment: @JimMischel If we can skip over empty buckets efficiently, it won't be a problem to make a bucket-based priority queue. So they are the same problem.

Comment: A bucket-based priority queue is no problem; just build a heap out of the buckets that are used.

Comment: @JimMischel Then it will be worse than using a heap directly in my case.

Comment: Again it will be difficult to help you out if you don't give us a concrete example.

Comment: @JimMischel Okay, I have added an example. Hope you will not suggest me  giving up bucket sort in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Your application must be special.  If buckets are sparse, one might expect that you would only have one or two items per bucket on average.  If so, then the bucket sort isn't doing you any good -- just put the items in a heap.

If buckets are not really that sparse, i.e., if the number of buckets is <= a few times the number of items, then the bucket sort suffices -- iterate through the buckets in order and the cost will be O(N) in the number of items.

If you have many items per non-empty bucket AND many buckets per item, then you probably want to explain your use case, but when I've seen this in the past it has been reasonable to insert each bucket into a heap when it becomes non-empty.

Comment: Here's my situation: the number of elements could be huge for heap, but the keys distribute sparsely. I was considering a two-level bucket queue but not so sure about its effectiveness.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is "Not without an additional data structure to keep track of which buckets have items."

There are multiple ways to do a bucket sort. The "best" depends a lot on the range of keys, the number of items, and the number of *unique* items. If your range is 0 to 1,000,000 and you know that you'll have, say, 50% unique, then a single array of 1,000,000 buckets is easy to work with, you don't waste too much space, and you don't waste a lot of time skipping over empty buckets.

But if you're talking a range of hundreds of millions that is very sparsely populated, you end up wasting a lot of memory and considerable time skipping over empty buckets. In extreme cases, you can't even allocate an array large enough to cover the entire range.

Another common way to implement a bucket sort is with a dictionary of hash map. The idea is:

```
initialize empty hash map
for each item in list
    if key already in hash map
        add item to that bucket
    else
        create new bucket in hash map
```

Of course, you then have to sort the buckets by key once you're done populating, but sorting a few thousand (if that) buckets takes trivial time. And you don't end up wasting gigabytes of memory on empty buckets.

When I built a bucket-based priority queue, I used the dictionary approach. I maintained a dictionary keyed by index, and added each item to the proper bucket. I also maintained a simple binary heap of the buckets. So adding an item to the heap became:

```
if item.key exists in dictionary
    dictionary[item.key].add(item)  // adds item to bucket
else
{
    dictionary.add(item.key, item) // creates a new bucket
    heap.push(dictionary[item.key]) // pushes the bucket onto the heap
}
```

And removing an item from the heap becomes:

```
bucket = heap.peek()
item = bucket.getFirst()
if (bucket.count() == 0)
{
    // bucket is empty. Remove from heap and from dictionary
    heap.pop()
    dictionary.remove(item.key)
}
return item
```

This performs quite well. Because my keys were sparse and the buckets heavily filled, it was rare that the heap itself got any activity. Most of the activity involved adding things to and removing things from buckets that were already in the heap. The only time the heap got exercise was when a bucket was emptied, or when I added a new bucket. So *on average*, both insert and remove were very close to O(1).

This worked well for me because my range of keys was very large (10-character alphanumeric), the number of individual items in the hundreds of millions, or billions, but the number of unique keys used at any time was in the thousands. There is some slight overhead is the dictionary indirection, but that's more than offset by the savings of working with a heap of a few thousand, rather than hundreds of millions, of items.